# Подвал не фиксированной высоты прижатый к низу экрана

Tags: веб-программирование, html, вёрстка, css

Привет!

Тема, конечно, банальна до ужаса. Но хотелось бы уже точно знать:

Есть ли способ прижать подвал не фиксированной(!) высоты к низу сайт без использования скриптов, что бы работало в IE8+?

Спасибо .)

P.S. Есть [вот такой](http://silverflame.at.tut.by/sticky1.html) способ, но когда я подключаю библиотеку jQuery (О_о) в хроме сайт "сжимается" по вертикали и подвал, естественно, уже не прижат к экрану.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день! Если я Вас правильно понимаю, то Вам нужно следующее:

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#content{
    min-height:70%;
    background:#369;
}
#footer{
    height:30%;
    background:#d33;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

---

**UPD:** Тогда, думаю, что Вам нужно вот это:

CSS:

```
    html,body{
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#d33;
    }
    #wrapper{
        display: table;
        height:100%;
    }
    #footer{
        background:#769;
        display: table-row;
        height:30%;
    }
    #wrapper, #footer{
        width:100%;
    }
    #content{
        background:#d33;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        text<br />
        text<br />
        text<br />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        text<br />
        text<br />
        text<br />
        text<br />
        text<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет. Вы не правильно поняли =) Мне нужно что бы подвал занимал высоту контента в нем. Там, например, может дублироваться навигация. Я не могу знать сколько будет пунктов меню что бы посчитать высоту.

Посмотрите тот способ, что я написал, он отлично работает, не считая странного взаимодействия с jQuery

Comment: см. UPD. В данном случае футер будет растягиваться в процентном соотношении. Если Вам необходимо, чтобы футер был только по высоте контента - задайте для #footer значение height равное 1%.

Comment: Вроде работает. Спасибо .)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос неправильно сформулирован, но я понял, что футер должен всегда быть прижат к низу. Вот несколько решений:

#### 1. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для фиксированной высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   content
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

#### 2. Решение через Flexbox для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  /* Чтобы занимал оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  /* Чтобы footer не уменьшался */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 3. Решение через таблицы для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: table-row;
  /* Чтобы ряд занимал всё оставшееся пространство, так как табличная разметка не позволит ему вытолкнуть header и footer */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 4. Решение с использованием jQuery для адаптивной высоты футера

```js
// Высчитываем высоту footer и делаем соответствующий отступ от main:
function footer(){
$('main').css('padding-bottom',$('footer').height());
}
window.addEventListener('load',footer);
window.addEventListener('resize',footer);
```

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer по умолчанию */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer по умолчанию */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```